# Suggested edits on Beta

Tags: support, edits, review, suggested-edits, beta-phase

Are the number of suggested edits on Beta Sites different to non-beta sites?

If there are many suggested edits made by a user, given the lack of users who can review suggested edits on beta.. if the [review queue](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/review/)is not processed prior to the suggested editor's rep reaching the editing threshold, do these edits automatically become "approved".

I ask this, as I have made a series of [suggested edits](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/3267/skippy?tab=activity) and it occurred to me, could I be reviewing my own suggested edits, as I am close to having editing privileges??

**Edit**

There is a total of [11 users on CogSci](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) who have reviewed more than 3 suggested edits in total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those suggested edits will not get approved, even if you reach the editing privileges.

And

I don't think there are lack of users for reviewing in [Cognitive Sciences beta Site](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/). If so, those less number of reviewers will review the remaining suggestions on the next day. For this reason, the number of approve votes required is less for the beta sites.

> could I be reviewing my own suggested edits?

No one can review their own posts.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but you may want to edit yr answer have a look at the edit in my question.. there is a lack of users for reviews

Comment: @Skippy, 11 reviewers are far enough to review 23 suggestions, and I already added in the answer that if there is a less number of active reviewers in a site, they could review the remaining edits on the next day, as these edits are all made on one day, so you should wait for that.

Comment: how many does it take to approve an edit?

Comment: @Skippy 2 on beta sites, or one moderator

Comment: also I have earned over 800 rep in 11 days, so it's reasonable to think I might hit 1000 before they are reviewed

Comment: @Skippy, if you are asking about time, I can't tell. Those edits may get review today itself, the OP of those posts can review the edits and all I can say is WAIT your reps are on the way :)

Comment: @Azik my issue is not the rep.. I have earned the vast majority of my rep from posts, I am thinking I should've waited until I reached 1000 before making so many edits, it's just created work.. I thought they would be automatically approved when I turn 1000

Comment: @Azik ok done and answered cheers.. u taught me something I didn't know ;) bye

Comment: @Rory It takes 2 votes to approve or reject on every site except SO where it takes 3.